# Undo, Redo, Copy, Cut tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I've taken the liberty of shortening the code to only fit my question I've been trying to figure out how to implement the undo, redo, copy, and cut button in a text editor I'm making in Python. I've seen some examples on the internet but I'm having issues implementing it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext as ScrolledText
from tkinter import Tk, scrolledtext, Menu, filedialog, messagebox, Text, simpledialog, filedialog
import requests
import urllib.request

#Functions
def donothing():
    messagebox.showinfo('Not Implimented', 'This option has not been implimented yet!')

root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

root.title('Written in Python')
root.minsize(width=100, height=100)
root.geometry('800x500+350+150') #Height, Width, X, Y coordinates of the program

#NotePad
textArea = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(root, width=100, height=100) #Height and width of notepad
textArea.pack()

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit",menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=donothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=donothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=donothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=donothing)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Cut, copy and paste look like a different question from the redo and undo problem. Search tkinter questions in SO for selection in text widget, and search for undo/redo in tkinter and/or  in general. Then show us code you have tried to do that and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, and this is what I did.

```
def delete():
    notepad.delete(0.0, END)

def redo():
    notepad.edit_redo()

def undo():
    notepad.edit_undo()
```